# How to enable In-App purchase without being Team Member

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am working on iOS App for the Customer. The Customer has created an iOS Team provisioning profile on his side, but he has not set up a development team yet, so I am not a team member. My current task is to support in-app purchases. The Customer has already created in-app id in his Member Center. When, in XCode, I go to *Target->Capabilities->In-App Purchase*, it says

"*To enable In-App purchase, select a Development Team to use for provisioning*"

Is there any alternative for waiting till the Customer grants me "team member" (he says it is not so easy, because he needs to switch his individual account to organization)? I know that the Customer can export his development certificate and private-key and send me, but will it help me to set In-App purchase capability for the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must build the app with a certificate and provisioning profile that is from the account for which iTunes Connect has the App created and the IAP products configured.  There is no alternative to this for a true test.

Having said that, if you have access to some other development account you could always create a dummy app in that account and setup some IAP products to test against.

Comment: Thank you very much, so what should I tell to the Customer (he is rather unexperienced)? Should I ask him for two things: certificate and provisioning profile? I know that certificate can be sent as .p12 file. In what form provisioning profile will be sent?

Comment: The provisioning profile would be sent as is, no need to wrap it in something.  It's a little more complex than that, unfortunately.  He'll also need to setup your test device in his iOS dev portal and an app ID for the app (which must be done prior to setting up the app in iTunes Connect anyway).  The provisioning profile will have both of these things selected along with the cert.